# Abstract Algebra - Permutations and Orders

Tags: abstract-algebra

The question is:
Suppose $\alpha \in S_n$ and $| \alpha |$ is odd. Prove that $\alpha \in A_n$.

So far all I know is that they have to be disjoint cycles. This is as far as I've gotten in my proof:

Pf: Assume $\alpha \in S_n$ and $| \alpha |$ is odd. Let $\alpha =C_1 C_2 ... C_r$ where the $C_i$ 's are disjoint cycles. Let $K_1 = \text{length }C_1$ , $K_2 = \text{length }C_2,\dotsc,  K_r = \text{length }C_r$.

I know that $\alpha$ can be written in an even number of transpositions but that's about all I know how to relate the two. I did see online someone use the "sign" of the permutations but I haven't learned that just yet. Suggestions?

Comment: Huh? Isn't the claim part of the assumption?

Comment: Thank you for catching that. It was supposed to be A_n

Comment: What definition do you use for $A_n$?

Comment: Also, what is $|\alpha|$ ?

Comment: A_n is a subgroup of S_n and |A_n| = n!/2   (so even permutations)
|   | refers to the order. So in this example, its asking for the order of an element.

Comment: If you haven't learnt about the sign function how do you define $A_n$? $A_n$ is usually defined as the even permutations (i.e. $sgn(\sigma)=1$). I think the easiest way to prove this is to use the fact that the sign function is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Since the order of $\alpha$ is odd, we have $\alpha^{2k+1}=\iota$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Define the sign function as:

$$
sgn(\sigma)=\left\{ \begin{array}{11} 1 & \text{if }\sigma \text{ is an even permutation} \\ -1 & \text{if }\sigma \text{ is an odd permutation}  \end{array} \right.
$$

Then $sgn$ is a homomorphism of groups and $sgn(\iota)=1$ so we must have:

$$
\begin{split} 1 &= sgn(\alpha^{2k+1}) \\ &=(sgn(\alpha))^{2k+1}  \end{split}
$$

which implies that $sgn(\alpha)=1$ so $\alpha$ is an even permutation and hence $\alpha\in A_n$.